# jsp dropdownlist not working

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying the following sample code for populating a dropdownlist in a jsp page but not items appears in the dropdown list. I can see the items in the dropdown in the view page source as follows.

page source:

java:
    package com.example;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

```
public class ListBean {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getItems() {
    System.out.println("Done adding to list");

    list.add("Thing1");
    list.add("Thing2");
    list.add("Thing3");

    return list;
}
private String old_list = "No list message.";
public String getSomething() {
    System.out.println("Get list");
   return old_list;
}

private String message = "No message.";
public String getMessage() {
    System.out.println("Get message");
   return message;
}
public void setMessage(String s) {
   message = s;
}   
}
```

html:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <jsp:useBean id="list" class="com.example.ListBean"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${list.items}">
            <option>${item}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<jsp:useBean>` and JSTL don't mix. Provide the relevant data as a request attribute from a Servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to import the JSTL *tag library*. Add the following *taglib* directive to your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: It works by importing JSTL lib but not after removing <jsp: useBeans>.

Comment: Yes, once I figured that you're instantiating, what seems to be a pre-populated List, I removed that. Please refresh your page to see the change.